# android how do i prevent mobile to download apps from playstore?

Tags: android

im creating anapplication which load user download aplication in list view im using database which  store playstore application id in database and match system install app with that database see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MsGs.jpg    in this image playstore give application package id=... in url

playstore give application in url which  is  id=air.com.ea.superherocity_row&feature  so that id is save in database so easily retrive that applictaion in listview which add frm playstore but problem is this if user dont view product detail and just click app install button see this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pM4Z.jpg     play store not show any id in url so that application not save in listview how do i prevent my mobile to must vew product detail other wise not install any app  form play store???

Comment: i just want to prevent user to must see application description in playstore then install appother wise not install any app

Comment: I would be very surprised if the answer turns out to be positive. Why on earth app developers want to take the freedom away from the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the behaviour of the Play Store app like this for the simple reason that it is not your app and they do not offer a setting or API you can use to do this.

Comment: how to i make condition in my mobile hardware to not install app in if condtion like(if url contain.(id) theninstall pa other wose not

Comment: @user2527915 Modify android at a source level and make your own ROM

Comment: so no any posiblilty to avoid install app  until user not see application detail???

Comment: Not without your own custom ROM or app store.